# Or tools timeTable with less gaps

Tags: python, optimization, or-tools, timetable, cp-sat

tools for a scheduling problem to generate a school timeTable with a cp-sat model.

Im using this model :
[image]

Im wanna add a soft constraint  to have less gaps as possible between lessons (free timeslots) but im struggling, i know i should use slack variables but im really stuck on how to start.

Any help or hint on how to do it is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: You could minimize the number of times that (l, r, t) is true and (l, r, t+1) is false or something like that

Comment: or minimize max(timeslots used) - min(timeslots used) - sum(timeslot used)

Comment: Is there an example that implements something similar to this beacause i understand the logic but i have no idea how to implement it in code and thanks.

Comment: @TarikOuhamou Could you please give a bit better description of what you're trying to achieve?